# Passing Google Charts DrawChart Method Data From An Angular Class

Tags: angular, google-visualization

So I am creating an Angular application and I am using Google Charts within this application.

First I have a user enter some information and then an appropriate chart is generated by fetching the information relevant to the user's input from a server i've built.

My issue is that i cannot access the information given to my component from the method that is drawing the chart.

For example:

```
declare var google: any;

...

 export class GymDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addressesService.active.subscribe(active => this.active = active);
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawDayGraphWithoutPredictive); // you cant have the parenthesis here

  }

  drawDayGraphWithoutPredictive() {
    const data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y');

    data.addRows(this.active.getPopulationData());

    const options = {
      title: 'Z',
      chartArea: {width: '70%' , height: '90%'},
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Time'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'X'
      }
    };

    const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('day_populations_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

In my drawDayGraphWithoutPreidctive method i would like to access information from my active object. Unfortunately all the component's properties are undefined while in this method so the line

```
     data.addRows(this.active.getPopulationData());
```

fails because active is undefined.

How do I pass data into this method?

Also i know that the active object has been set appropriately because the other html that uses it is rendering properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.drawDayGraphWithoutPredictive(this.active));
```

is how you solve it.